# What mining resource will make the most money? Elite Dangerous

Tags: elite-dangerous-horizons

I'm core mining in an Asp Scout.  Been doing pretty good, made three runs with an average profit of 2,000,000 credits per run, mining one asteroid per run.  I've pretty much figured out the mechanics of core mining, but I am trying to figure out which resources I should be searching for.  So far I've mined Platinum and Rhodplumsite.  Those are pretty good, but I'm hoping to make more than 2 mil a run (not sure if that's possible with my current ship).  Which resource is worth the most (that i can get core mining) and where can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most profitable core mining material is either Void Opals or Low Temperature Diamonds. Void opals are commonly found around Icy rings. There are worth upwards of 650k per ton. My mining Clipper averages 220mil per void run, as an example of the potential gains you can have by focusing on a single material.

Mining one asteroid and calling it quits is a very inefficient way of mining, continue to search until your cargo bay is full or you run out of limpets. Below is a full guide created by another CMDR that will help get things going in the right direction, what to look for, and additional tips.

o7

[image]

Comment: yeah, before you posted this I made the most I've made in one haul, 9 mil.  I mined Alexandrite and Void Opals, but I'm not sure i get it.  The galactic average for Alexandrite was about 200,000, and the Void Opals around 100,000 if i remember correctly,  so why are the Void Opals worth more?  I'm currently docked at Col 285 Sector CC-K A38-2 1, because I heard it's a great spot for diamond mining.

Comment: Ok, I mined 14 low temp diamonds, but their average value is only 106,000.  Why are they the best?

Comment: the value of minerals vary drastically. check something like INARA https://inara.cz/galaxy-commodity/10250/ regularly and jump to where void opals are in a boom state. the system where it is mined usually won't be where you sell.

Comment: Use [edtools](https://edtools.cc/miner) to find out what system pays best for the minerals you mined. Try to strike a balance between price and distance.
Also consider selling to Fleet Carriers parked in the system. They may pay under-market rates, but they often sell limpets too, meaning you can get back to mining a whole lot quicker and yield better profit/hour.

Comment: Also, if you like and use the edtools, consider helping the community and run the [EDMC](https://github.com/EDCD/EDMarketConnector/wiki) while you play E:D.